# Using .on in directive VS in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What would be considered as best practice, attaching directive to element or binding event inside the controller?

**Directive**

```
<openread-more what-to-expand="teds-bets-readmore" />

myApp.directive('openreadMore', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        template: '<a class="attach-event" what-to-expand="readmore1">Event</a></span>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function () {
                // attached code on click
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Just attaching it inside the controller**

```
homepageCtrls.controller('homepageCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.attach-event')).on('click', function () {
         // attached code on click              
    });
});
```

The second option seems shorter and much cleaner, but i don't know if it's considered as best practice or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick) directive.

```
<openread-more what-to-expand="teds-bets-readmore" ng-click="doSomeAction()" />
```

And on the controller:

```
homepageCtrls.controller('homepageCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doSomeAction = function() {
       // onClick logic here...
    };
});
```

### Edit

In case you are binding other kind of events, just make this question to yourself: "Will I have different behaviours for this event depending on the current view or application state?".

If the answer is **yes** then you should register the event handlers on the controllers. If the answer is **no** (which means you will have always the same behaviour) then register and handle the events on the directive.

Nevertheless, **you should not access UI elements on the controllers** (e.g. don't use selectors or anything similar). The controllers are supposed to be reusable, which means you should be able to use them on different UIs, with different UI elements. The best approach is to define a directive that allows you to bind specific events, like Angular UI [Event Binder](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/).

Comment: I'm aware of ng-click, but in case i need to bind events - what would have been a better choice ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check if it helps.